# Configure DDS with scrapy-splash. ERROR: no base objects

Tags: django, django-dynamic-scraper, scrapy-splash

LS,

I have installed Django-Dynamic-Scraper. And i would like to render Javascript via Splash. Therefor i have installed scrapy-splash and installed the docker splash image. The image below shows that the docker container can be reached.

[Splash docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk0iC.png)

Nevertheless when i test it via DDS it returns the following error:

```
2016-10-25 17:06:00 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-10-25 17:06:00 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-10-25 17:06:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-10-25 17:06:05 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://192.168.0.150:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2016-10-25 17:06:06 [root] ERROR: No base objects found!
2016-10-25 17:06:06 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-10-25 17:06:06 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

when executing:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -a id=1
```

I have configured the DDS admin page and checked the checkbox to render the javascript:

[Admin configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnX6c.png)

I have followed the configuration from scrapy-splash:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# SPLASH SETTINGS
# https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#configuration
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.0.150:8050/'

DSCRAPER_SPLASH_ARGS = {'wait': 3}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

# This middleware is needed to support cache_args feature;
# it allows to save disk space by not storing duplicate Splash arguments
# multiple times in a disk request queue.
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

# If you use Scrapy HTTP cache then a custom cache storage backend is required.
# scrapy-splash provides a subclass
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

I assume with a correct configuration of DDS/scrapy-splash, it will sends the required arguments to the splash docker container to render, Is this the case?

What am I missing? Do i need to adjust the spider with a splash script?